# Не могу спарсить текст php

Tags: php, html

Пытаюсь спарсить из

```
<div class="one_home_reserv "> 
                                    <div class="one_home_reserv_ico currency_logo" style="background-image: url(https://vv-obmen.ru/wp-content/uploads/Qiwi.png);"></div>
                                    <div class="one_home_reserv_block">
                                        <div class="one_home_reserv_title">
                                            Qiwi RUB                                        </div>
                                        <div class="one_home_reserv_sum">
                                            -9 553                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                                                                     
                                <div class="one_home_reserv last_item"> 
                                    <div class="one_home_reserv_ico currency_logo" style="background-image: url(https://vv-obmen.ru/wp-content/uploads/Advcash.png);"></div>
                                    <div class="one_home_reserv_block">
                                        <div class="one_home_reserv_title">
                                            Advcash USD                                     </div>
                                        <div class="one_home_reserv_sum">
                                            673.89                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
```

Значение "673.89"

```
function Parse($p1, $p2, $p3) {
    $num1 = strpos($p1, $p2);
    if ($num1 === false) return 0;
    $num2 = substr($p1, $num1);
    return strip_tags(substr($num2, 0, strpos($num2, $p3)));
}
 
$String = file_get_contents($link);


echo Parse($String, '<div class="one_home_reserv_title"> Advcash USD</div>', '</div>
```

Получаю в ответ "0"

Как решить?

Comment: о, Януля вернулась .... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1435492/191482 ......

Comment: кто чей мульт? этот или тот?